# Why when enter two char[] , the first one will become the same as the last one?

Tags: c++, char

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char b[50];
    cin >> b;
    char* a[50];
    a[0] = b;
    cin >> b; 
    cout << endl;
    a[1] = b;
    cout << a[0] << "\t" << a[1] << endl;
    cout << strlen(a[0])<<"\t"<<strlen(a[1]) << endl;
}
```

---

**input and output**

- abc
- 123456
- 123456  123456
- 6       6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char* a[50]` is an array of pointers to strings.

`char b[50]` is a string (an array of characters)

So this

```
char b[50] = "x";
char* a[50];
a[0] = b;
a[1] = b;
```

Is the same as

```
char b[50] = "x";
char* a0 = b;
char* a1 = b;
```

In both cases, both pointers point to the same string (`b`).  If you change what is in that string, then both pointers point to the same place they pointed before: the string `b` but now with changed contents.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same because you're accessing the same memory (the array named `b`) when you dereference `a[0]` and `a[1]`.

Btw: Don't use plain old char arrays for strings in C++. Use `std::string` or something similar.